# Difficulties converting JSON to GeoJSON

Tags: python, json, twitter, geojson

My code is supposed to collect tweets related to a given query, output them to a JSON file, then iterate down that JSON file to pull out information and format the output as a geoJSON for import into QGIS.

Everything seems to be functioning except the iteration method - when the script is run, it will output all the tweets to the JSON, but it will only pull one tweet from the JSON file to drop into the geoJSON file.
Here's the code:

```
# Imports Twython API client authorization, json library
import json
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

# API connection via Tweepy

# Defines the API Consumer Key and Secret used to authenticate with Twitter
API_KEY = 'API key'
API_SECRET = 'API Secret'
TOKEN_KEY = 'Token Key'
TOKEN_SECRET = 'Token Secret'

auth = OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
# Stores pulled tweets to .json file
def tstore(tweet):
    out_file = open("test.json","a")
    json.dump(tweet, out_file)
    out_file.write("\n")
    out_file.close()

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q="#Lakers",
                           count=100,
                           geocode="33.7683,-118.1955,25mi").items():
    tstore(tweet._json)
print "Done with Cursor"


with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    geo_data = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": []
    }
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        if tweet['coordinates']:
            geo_json_feature = {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": tweet['coordinates'],
                "properties": {
                    "text": tweet['text'],
                    "created_at": tweet['created_at']
                }
            }
            geo_data['features'].append(geo_json_feature)
print "Next Stage" 
# Save geo data
with open('geo_data.json', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(json.dumps(geo_data, indent=4))
```

Comment: You should try `print(line)` to see if it really looks like a JSON.

Comment: Output is:
{

    "contributors": null, 

then the Traceback error.

Comment: Here is your issue: `{ "contributors": null` is not a valid JSON format, so `json.loads()` fails.The data format of your `test.json` does not suit your code, you should ensure that there is exactly one JSON object per line, or you can rewrite your parsing function.

Comment: How would I go about doing this in the code listed above? would I add /n in the tstore(tweet.json) portion? Sorry, I'm very new at this and most of the training I've had has been very very limited to a particular library (arcpy) and I'm trying to break away from that so that I can use more opensource tools.

Comment: I did not noticed that your `test.json` was actually created by your code, so you can indeed quite easily fix it. You may try to remove `indent=4` so JSON will entirely be on the same line. As you said, you will also probably need to write "\n" before each JSON appended.

Comment: Okay, so now it lets me go through beyond the cursor, but python crashes following completion of the cursor component. No errors, just a freeze, "this program is not responding", and then crash.

Probably has something to do with the test.json beginning to exceed 25MB...

Comment: Indeed, 25MB is quite a huge file, but I think it should be ok anyway. Are you sure that there is one tweet on each line, and not all the tweets on the same line? How can the file be so heavy if there is only 100 tweets? Also, you may try to create the `geo_json_feature` at the same time that you get it from `tweepy.Cursor()`, this will prevent having to call `json.loads()`, even if I do not think this really matters.

Comment: The load functionality needs to be set up because it needs to be formatted, since by default twitter puts it's latitudinal and longitudinal coordinates in the reversed order from what's necessary for a geoJSON file.

It may all be on one line; I'm not sure where I should be putting the /n into the code.

Comment: Try to add `out_file.write("\n")` right after your `json.dump()`.

Comment: I don't know if I should post the code i have now, or not - I'm at a point where I've gotten it to stop popping out errors, but instead of iterating through the test.json, it's only pulling out one of the tweets and dropping it into the geo_data.json

Comment: I think you should update your question if your code and issue changed.

Comment: Question updated, thank you. Still getting familiar with StackExchange. Seriously, thank you for your help and seemingly endless patience.

Comment: No problem. ;) However, I can not see why this is not working now. Try to remove your line `line = f.readline()` which losts the first line of your file.

Comment: The problem appears to have been that my query radius was too small for what I was asking for - it's not that it wasn't iterating, it's just that the set of tweets I downloaded in my radius only had one geo-tagged tweet to pull out.

Of course, I immediately increased my radius too high (1000 mi), hit the rate limit, and need to play around with narrowing it down before my class deadline.

Thank you so much for your help; how do I give you rep/up you as the top answer?

Comment: It's ok, don't worry. But you can answer your question and accept your own response, as you succeeded to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The iteration is functioning; the issue was lack of geocoded tweets in the samples being returned by Twitter. Solved by larger search radius or more inclusive query terms.